# Trouble reading Secrets from Jenkins Credential Manager in Pipeline job using Credential Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline job that uses a secret value in `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        echo "DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The secret value is stored in Credentials Manager as `secret text` with the ID `DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER`. I parameterized my Jenkins pipeline job by referring to the secret text from Credential Manager:

[image]

I'm trying to read this value in `Jenkinsfile` as shown above but I get the following output:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER
[Pipeline] sh
```

It just prints the ID of the credential but not the value. I thought it might be a Jenkins security mechanism but when I try and do something similar with a Freestyle job, I get a masked output (`******`).

But what DOES work is if I use a parameter in my pipeline job but instead of a `Credential Parameter` I use a `String Parameter` or `Password Parameter` - then the secret value gets printed out:

[image]

So I'm either not using the `Credential Parameter` correctly or there's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it's supposed to work. To actually make use of that reference to a Jenkins credentials, you need to use [credentials binding plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/). For example, if your credentials are of type 'Username and password' you'll do as follows:

```
withCredentials([userNamePassword: $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER, usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']) {
  echo "DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is $USER and password is $PASSWORD"
}
```

Nota that Jenkis will not show private credentials in the output, but the value it is properly populated.

Comment: I'm now trying to do the same thing but for a multi-branch pipeline job and it's not as simple as for a pipeline job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875645/trouble-reading-secrets-from-jenkins-credential-manager-in-multi-branch-pipeline