# Trouble reading Secrets from Jenkins Credential Manager in Multi Branch Pipeline job using Credential Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins **multi branch** pipeline job that uses a secret value in `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        echo "DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is ${env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER_NSV}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The secret value is stored in Credentials Manager as secret text with the ID `DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER_NSV`:

[image]

I'm trying to read this value in Jenkinsfile as shown above but I get the following output that prints out the value `null` for my secret:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is null
[Pipeline] sh
```

I also tried referencing the secret text in my pipeline like this:

```
echo "DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER_NSV}"
```

But then I get this error when running the Jenkins job:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER_NSV for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
```

I think I need to bind that credential to the job but I don't see an option to do that for a Multi-Branch Pipeline job, the way you can for a Freestyle or Pipeline job.

How can I use a secret credential in a Multi Branch Pipeline job?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [credentials()](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) helper method to archive your purpose.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER = credentials('DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER_NSV') 
                               // put the ID of credential as credentials()'s parameter.
    }

    stages {

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER is ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER}"
            }
        }
   }

}
```